# How to print HQ vinyl self-adhesive stickers

Tags: vinyl, cutter

I'm doing some research and was wondering if you can help :)

I'm trying to figure it out how to print (and obviously cut) vinyl stickers for cards with the size of a standard debit/credit card. I need the stickers to be durable (strongly adhesive to the plastic) and for the print/ink not to wear out easy; waterproof would be a nice feature as well.

I've read that one can achieve all the things above by using a good inkjet printer with Papilio Inkjet waterproof vinyl. Is it true? Moreover is there a similar solution for laser printers?

As for the cutting, what kind of equipment I would need to achieve nice round edges?

I have a small graphic design business, specializing in 3D CGI and video effects but it's not going very well :( Recently a friend of mine who's working for a huge company told me that he can get me a contract for printing stickers for the employees' security cards (photo of the person and some text), which are the size of a debit card. Unfortunately I have no experience with these things so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you can test some of these inkjet solutions out and see for yourself how they work? Frankly any printer business worth their salt would be a better solution as they have both the expertise and the equipment to this very cost-effectively. I'm not trying to shoot down your next business opportunity but do realize you're going to be competing with these printers that do this 24/7 and have dealt with issues you haven't even run into (yet). All this being said, now is a good a time as any to learn something new!

Comment: I think ultimately it's cheaper and easier to just use a print services such as gotprint, vistaprint, printingforless. overnightprints, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a lot cheaper to outsource but if you really want to at school we have sheets of adhesive vinyl and we just feed it into a laser cutter which cuts it out for us.

If you really want names I might be able to get them but it would be a large start up cost as you will need special software etc.